# How do I remove this awkward plane?

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

Using `Plot3D`, I tried to plot $x^3 + y^3+3xy=z$

```
 Plot3D[x^3 + y^3 + 3 x y, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, PlotRange -> {-10, 20}, 
    PlotStyle -> Directive[Yellow, Specularity[White, 20], Opacity[0.8]]]
```

Now for some reason *Mathematica* generates this awkward blue plane out of nowhere and I cannot find a way to remove it since I do not even know what it is

[image]

I am on *Mathematica* 8.0.4

Comment: as far as i'm aware that's where the function is being clipped by the containing plot range. change plot range with PlotRange and change clipping style with ClippingStyle

Comment: Add this option `ClippingStyle -> None`.

Comment: Ahhhhg, just saw the comments.  Happy to withdraw my answer if one of you wants to supplant it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Plot3D[x^3 + y^3 + 3 x y, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, 
 PlotRange -> {-10, 20}, 
 PlotStyle -> Directive[Yellow, Specularity[White, 20], Opacity[0.8]],
  ClippingStyle -> None]
```

[image]

`ClippingStyle -> None` does the trick